# glGetAttribLocation vs glBindAttribLocation

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

On iOS devices is it wise to bind attributes (and how do you choose the index number to bind to)? In my application, I have several shaders, and keeping track of all the attributes/uniforms is getting cumbersome. But I've read that [nVidia imposes restrictions](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/attributes.php) on indexes, and that has me thinking `glBindAttribLocation` should be avoided in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*But I've read that nVidia imposes restrictions on indexes*"

1. What you're talking about is for *Desktop OpenGL*, which is not the same as OpenGL ES. So it doesn't apply to you.
2. This is incorrect even for desktop GL. It is true that NVIDIA does illegally alias between built-in attributes and user-defined ones. But that's irrelevant if you *never use* built-in attributes. And you shouldn't. So if you don't, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: So, would it be appropriate then to define some constants like `const int ATTRIBUTE_VERTICES = 25;` that would be bound to all of my shaders that had an attribute for vertices? Also, how do I come up with the number `25`? Is there certain numbers that I cannot use?

Comment: @Mr.Smith: "*Also, how do I come up with the number 25? Is there certain numbers that I cannot use?*" The [docs for `glBindAttribLocation`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml) tells you what the viable locations are.

Comment: I've seen that page a dozen times, it only tells you the upper limit. For instance, is 0 a valid index?

Comment: @Mr.Smith: The page says that `index` is an unsigned integer (`GLuint`) which must be less than `GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS`. 0 is an unsigned integer that is less than `GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS`. You're really over-complicating something that is *very simple*. The page says what the allowed range of indices are. That is the allowed range of indices.

Answer (score 3):

ive found the best way to manage attributes and uniforms is to have an enum

```
enum
{
UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX,
UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX,
UNIFORM_VEC3_lightPosition,
UNIFORM_VEC4_lightDiffuseColour,
UNIFORM_VEC4_lightSpecularColour,
UNIFORM_VEC4_lightAmbientColour,
UNIFORM_VEC3_lightHalfVector,
UNIFORM_Texture,
UNIFORM_VEC4_NumberColour,
UNIFORM_VEC4_FaceColour,
UNIFORM_VEC4_camerPosition,
NUM_UNIFORMS
};

GLint uniforms[NUM_UNIFORMS];
```

then when you init your shaders

```
// Get uniform locations.
uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX] = glGetUniformLocation(Program, "modelViewProjectionMatrix");
uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX] = glGetUniformLocation(Program, "normalMatrix");
uniforms[UNIFORM_VEC3_lightPosition] = glGetUniformLocation(Program, "lightPosition");
//etc
```

and then when using them

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, normalMatrix.m);
//etc
```

not sure if this is what you were really asking about, but its useful none the less.

Comment: I've seen that used before, but what if you have more than one program?

Comment: could use a 2d array and use multiple enums or something like uniforms[COOL_SHADER][UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX]
uniforms[LIGHTING_SHADER][UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX]

Comment: That would only be easier IF it could be assumed that I never had to change the indexes or number of attributes/uniforms of an existing shader. If I ever have to change either of those, it would simpler to just define them all separately.

Comment: but having NUM_UNIFORMS defined at the end of the enum would take care of that pretty much, each time you add something new to the enum it will automatically figure out the size of the arrays etc at compile time. Or is that not what you mean?